# Displacement of <td> and <tr>

Tags: html

This **should** be super easy to solve. I have the following code that is not working the way I would like it to. The aim is to have something like this, with the BUTTON on the right of the "1 2 3 4 table":

```
1    2       BUTTON
3    4
```

but all I get is almost the same disposition with the button as a 3rd line. What am I missing?

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <tr>
            <td>1 </td>
            <td>2 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3 </td>
            <td>4 </td>
        </tr>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="but">
            <input type="button" class="button" value="BUTTON" />
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have an inner table, it needs its own set of `<table>` tags:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>1 </td>
                    <td>2 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3 </td>
                    <td>4 </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="but">
                <input type="button" class="button" value="BUTTON" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Otherwise, your "inner" `tr`s are actually being treated as a second and third row in your outer table, causing the displacement. The `td` containing the button appears in a new row *after* the rows with numbers. The result is a table with missing a `<tr>` start tag and some unexpected `<td>`/`</td>` tags. Here's your original markup re-indented and "fixed" (including the outer `<table>`/`</table>` tags that for whatever reason are not shown in the question) to show you what I mean:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
    <tr>
        <td>1 </td>
        <td>2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3 </td>
        <td>4 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="but">
                <input type="button" class="button" value="BUTTON" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note that `<tr>` and `<td>` have optional end tags, which means the markup above is completely valid even though the first `tr` and `td` are missing their end tags, and is the reason why your original markup is being treated the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

You should move your button to the first table row. And your HTML is not valid — you can't put [`<tr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr) into [`<td>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td), only vice versa. From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element):

> [Contexts in which this element can be used](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-dfn-contexts):
>   As a child of a `thead` element.
>   As a child of a `tbody` element.
>   As a child of a `tfoot` element.
>   As a child of a `table` element, after any `caption`, `colgroup`, and `thead` elements, but only if there are no `tbody` elements that are children of the `table` element.

Check out my snippet:

```css
td {
  padding: 5px 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1 </td>
        <td>2 </td>
        <td>
            <div class="but">
                <input type="button" class="button" value="BUTTON" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3 </td>
        <td>4 </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So can't put <tr> under a <td>, understood that. The code you put solve my problem partially, since I need the Button outside of the "rows with the numbers". In my full code they're inside a javascript if statement that can print 1 or more rows of pairs of strings (the numbers 1-2, 3-4 in this example) and I want the Button always on the right of the first row, independently from how many rows I have.

Answer (score 1):

You have included eveything inside one `<tr>` tag. You need 2 separate `<tr>` tags, i.e, 2 rows and **button** should be outside the `<table>` tag.

Then using **CSS** you need to set the `display` of both table and button to `inline-block` and then using `position` property of **CSS**, you can position button to the desired position.

As you also want some **space** between two columns of the table, you can use `&emsp;` to add some space between two columns of your table.

To add some space between **table** and **button**, add some `padding` to the **left side** of the **button**.

```css
.but {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

table {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>&emsp;&emsp;</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>&emsp;&emsp;</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="but">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="BUTTON" />
</div>
```

Comment: This also solves my question, but I prefer BoltClock's one because uses just the table displacement. Your's is useful forthe CSS positioning however, and will come in handy to me